# Not able to create a simplе application in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to create a simple RoR 3.2.3 application but I'm not able to it. It seems I installed something wrong.
Here is the code from Ubuntu console

```
    ~$ rails test
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/rails:18


    ~$ rails -v
    Rails 3.2.3


    ~$ ruby -v
    ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

    ~$ gem -v
    1.8.15
```

What should I do to resolve it?

Comment: Did you install with RVM and install ALL necessary dependencies?

Comment: @Mischa: it gives the same result.

Comment: @KyleMacey, now I installed rvm and some dependencies. I don't know if I installed all of them. So which ones should I install? I also updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `gem list`, do you see `railties` in the list?

You can always [clear out](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting/) your rvm installation by running `rvm implode`.  Try a fresh install, paying attention the different types of installations, particularly if you are performing a multi-user installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this package http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack it has all you need to start!

Comment: Is it an installer? If so I wouldn't like to use it, I would rather install via terminal.